Designing a Personalized Dashboard with Limited Space - Best Practices? pen_spark
I'm redesigning a dashboard to focus on personalized content that's easy to understand for the user. The challenge is to present the most relevant information within a limited space.
I'm familiar with the concept of user research and data integration for personalization, but I'm looking for best practices on:
Prioritizing information for personalization: Are there established methods to identify which data points are most valuable to individual users?
Visually representing personalized data: What are effective ways to present personalized information in a clear and concise way, especially with limited space?
Balancing user control vs. pre-defined personalization: Should users have options to customize their dashboard, or should the system primarily present pre-defined, personalized views?
Any insights or examples of successful personalized dashboards with limited space would be greatly appreciated!

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
